# Using sbt plugin from Bintray

Tags: scala, sbt, bintray

I'm experiencing a kind of impedance mismatch between `sbt` and `bintray-sbt` plugin. The plugin is published via `bintray-sbt` at `https://bintray.com/artifact/download/synapse/sbt-plugins/me/synapse/my-sbt-plugin/0.0.1/my-sbt-plugin-0.0.1.pom` (`publishMavenStyle` set to `true`. If set to `false` a different directory structure is created but still not the one sbt expects). Test project has

```
resolvers += Resolver.bintrayRepo("synapse", "sbt-plugins")

addSbtPlugin("me.synapse" % "my-sbt-plugin" % "0.0.1")
```

in `project/plugins.sbt` and sbt tries to download `https://dl.bintray.com/synapse/sbt-plugins/me/synapse/my-sbt-plugin_2.10_0.13/0.0.1/my-sbt-plugin-0.0.1.pom`

What settings should be used in plugin build definition to a) be able to test it from current repository and b) to be able to link it to sbt-plugin-releases repo when the time comes?

UPD: It looks like after the package was linked to sbt-plugin-releases it ended up in proper directory structure.